# C++ how to retrieve information from node with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, linked-list

For this project there is a linked list of an individual's information which consists of first name, last name, an integer, and a double. It looks like this:

```
void DonorList::addDonor(string firstName, string lastName, int memberID, double donation)
{
    Node *pNode = new Node(DonorType(firstName, lastName, memberID, donation), nullptr);

    if (first == nullptr)
    {
        first = pNode;
        last = pNode;
    }
    else
    {
        last->setLink(pNode);
        last = pNode;
    }
}
```

It inherits from the DonorType class. What I'm stumped at is how I can match only one parameter out of the 4 in a search function. I've tried the following:

```
bool DonorList::searchID(int memberNumber)
{
    Node *current = first;
    bool found = false;
    while (current != nullptr || !found)
    {
        if (current->getDonor() == memberNumber)
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

But of course it doesn't work because I can't compare current->getDonor() (the node of type DonorType) to memberNumber (which is an int). If it's any help, this is the Node class in the header file:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(){}
    Node(const DonorType& theDonor, Node *theLink) 
        : donor(theDonor), link(theLink){}
    Node* getLink( ) const { return link; }
    DonorType getDonor( ) const { return donor; }
    void setDonor(const DonorType& theDonor) 
        { donor = theDonor; }
    void setLink(Node *theLink) { link = theLink; }
private:
    DonorType donor;        
    Node *link;     //pointer that points to next node
};
```

So pretty much right now I'm very lost on how I can access the memberNumber information in the nodes in order to do a search function. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! This project actually has a bunch more files but I did my best to include what I believe is relevant to the issue.

Edit: Here's the DonorTypen class:

```
class DonorType : public MemberType
{
public:
    DonorType();
    DonorType(const string& firstName, const string& lastName, const int& memberNumber, const double& donationAmount);

    void setDonorInfo(string &firstName, string &lastName, int &memberNumber, double &donationAmount);
    void setAmountDonated(double &donationAmount);

    double getAmountDonated() const;

    void printDonor() const;
    void printDonation() const;

    ~DonorType();

private:
    double donation;
};
```

Edit2: MemberType class

```
class MemberType
{
public:
    MemberType();
    MemberType(const string& firstName, const string& lastName, const int& memberNumber);

    void setMemberInfo(const string& firstName, const string& lastName, const int& memberNumber);

    string getFirstName() const;
    string getLastName() const;
    int getMembershipNo();

    void printName() const;
    void printMemberInfo() const;

    ~MemberType();

private:
    string fname;
    string lname;
    int idnum;
};
```

Comment: we need to see the DonorType class. Although that seems odd that DonorType include that donors name, id, etc

Comment: There's nothing in the shown code that "inherits from the DonorType class", as you claim. Looks like there's a lack of a good grasp of C++ fundamental concepts. This is not something that can be properly handled in the space of a brief answer on stackoverflow.com. In order to be able to communicate a clear question that's answerable, being able to communicate using proper terminology, and common terms.

Comment: and why arent you using std::list

Comment: Edited OP to include DonorType class. Edit: @pm100 I'm using namespace std (yeah I know it's said to be bad practice but that's just what we're doing right now).

Comment: and membertype please

Comment: @pm100 Probably because professor's creativity is limited to *struct wiring*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Node::getDonor()` returns a `DonorType` object, which has methods for accessing the individual values, eg:

```
bool DonorList::searchID(int memberNumber)
{
    Node *current = first;
    while (current)
    {
        if (current->getDonor().getMembershipNo() == memberNumber)
        {
            return true;
        }
        current = current->getLink(); // <-- you also need to add this!
    }
    return false;
}
```

On a side note, I would suggest changing `Node::getDonor()` to return a `DonerType&` reference instead.  That way you are not creating copies of data each time `getDonor()` is called, and also so that things like `node->getDonor().set...()` will work as expected.

Also, your `addDonor()` implementation can be simplified to this:

```
void DonorList::addDonor(string firstName, string lastName, int memberID, double donation)
{
    Node *pNode = new Node(DonorType(firstName, lastName, memberID, donation), nullptr);

    if (!first)
        first = pNode;

    if (last)
        last->setLink(pNode);
    last = pNode;
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I changed it to "current->getDonor().getMembershipNo() == memberNumber" like you guys suggested and now I get error C3867 ('MemberType::getMembershipNo': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member).  It's apparently some kind of inheritance issue? That's also along 2 other errors which are '==': no conversion from 'int' to 'int (_thiscall MemberType:*)(void) and '==': 'int (_thiscall MemberTyupe:*)(void); differs in levels of indirection from 'int'. Oh but this is runtime error only, as the compiler isn't complaining anymore unless I try to debug.

Comment: The statement `if (current->getDonor().getMembershipNo() == memberNumber)` cannot produce those errors.  More likely, you wrote it as `if (current->getDonor().getMembershipNo == memberNumber)` instead.  Notice the missing parenthesis on `getMembershipNo`.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing out that typo. It's at least running now.

Answer (score 2):

you need

```
bool DonorList::searchID(int memberNumber)
{
    Node *current = first;
    bool found = false;
    while (current != nullptr || !found)
    {
        if (current->getDonor().getMembershipNo() == memberNumber)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else current = current->getLink();
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: You are not incrementing `current`, so if the first node is not a match then you will be stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: :-) I was assuming all the code was correct apart from the bit testing the membernumber. fixed

Comment: `Node::link` is `private` and `DonorList` is not a `friend` of `Node`, so `current = current.link;` will not work (and is wrong syntax anyway, you need `->` instead of `.`).